# use doThrow() to NOT throw an exception like doThrow(null, NullPointerException.class)

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I need something like `doThrow(null, NullPointerException.class).when(myService).m1()` to throw no exception on the first call of `void m1()` and a `NullPointerException` on the second call.

`doThrow()` does not accept `null`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

`doNothing().doThrow(NullPointerException.class).when(myService).m1();`

For non-void methods it can be done the same way:

```
 when(obj.methodName()).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class)
                       .thenReturn(something);
```

Comment: @gstackoverflow Never faced such a problem. Do you follow all the advice from the docs to https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/MockitoSession.html?

Comment: I've reread this page one more time and I still don't see any advice there. BTW I don't use MockitoSession directly. Framework uses it under the hood.